# Mount for a drill with 50 mm collar

Tags: drill, mount

Having just moved into a house (from a flat) for the first time in my life), I am about to buy a corded drill. I would like to get something "universal", suitable for drilling the walls to hang a TV or get a cable through the wall into the garden, and also to drill in the laminate and wood. I have a screw driver that I'm using to assemble furniture and do some very simple drilling. But it was already not powerful enough to drill the laminate plate for the heating pipe, I had to borrow a proper drill.

With this in mind, I thought of buying a [Metabo UHE 2450](https://www.metabo.com/com/en/machines/drilling-screwing-chiselling-stirring/rotary-and-chipping-hammers/2-gear-multihammers-sds-plus/uhe-2450-multi-600696390-multihammer.html). It does just about everything I can think of. It's an SDS-plus hammer, so good for drilling walls and potential garden works. It also accepts both an SDS and a quick-release chucks, to hold all bit types (I have quite a few non-SDS drill bits already). It has two gears, for normal SDS operation and for faster drilling. So a perfect choice.

However, I've just realized it has a 50 mm diameter collar. I've never seen one before, the standard being 43 mm. I'd like to be able to use accessories, something like [this drill stand](http://www.wolfcraft.com/en/products/p/drill_guides/1_tecmobil_mobile_drill_stand/s/p/index.html). So I wonder: what can I use such collar for and is there anything like a 50 to 43 mm converter? Or is maybe the path I've chosen wrong for some other reason?

**Update:** I am in Europe, the walls are apparently from brick (at least outside, potentially concrete inside judging from the first pair of holes I had to make with the borrowed hammer drill, but I've never had brick walls before so I could be mistaken). Drilling concrete ceiling and floors is also a possibility.

Comment: Unless you have concrete walls that drill is massive overkill. (It may be even if you do have concrete walls.) It's going to be heavy, cumbersome, and *slow*. Why not one of the new crop of lithium cordless drills? They're nothing short of amazing in terms of power and capability.

Comment: Perhaps the OP can return to tell us if masonry drilling is on the menu... (and I'm guessing the answer is yes, given the European hints). If so, I'd strongly support this kind of a drill. As far as the collar is concerned, if you really think you'll want a drill stand, then by all means buy a drill that'll work with it. However, the drill stand is a poor cousin to a real drill press and (in my opinion) not worth buying in the first place.

Comment: I'll second the sentiment regarding the drill stand item. Piece of junk that is not worth the money spent on it.

Comment: I have to comment, being the owner of some 5 corded drills, that there are times the job at had will be exceedingly awkward with a drill like that. Varying styles, sizes and features fit to a variety of work tasks.

Comment: I am in Europe, the walls are apparently from brick (at least outside, potentially concrete inside judging from the first pair of holes I had to make with the borrowed hammer drill, but I've never had brick walls before so I could be mistaken). Drilling concrete ceiling and floors is also a possibility.

Comment: @AloysiusDefenestrate: I don't want to use the stand instead of a press drill. It's more for drilling in the edge of a wooden plate or under 45°, or where I want a hole really orthogonal to the wall (when making through holes).

Comment: @MichaelKaras: Do I understand you right that you suggest `not` to take a universal tool but rather wait till I need something specific and then get it? My problem is that I already know that I need a proper corded drill (e.g. to hang the TV) `and` to be able to drill at right angles.

Comment: @texnic - That is what I do. Get the proper tool for the job. (All my power tools are corded).

Comment: I still like the drill as linked, but if you really think you'll need the drill stand, then don't get it until you can assure yourself that an appropriate drill stand exists. (But I should note I'm still not enthusiastic about the guide, because very close to 90 or 45 degrees is usually close enough. You can set up various aids to perfect drilling, such as blocks that you follow the angle of.) (Parenthetically, I should say that I'm a big fan of battery tools, but in this application, I think the corded one wins.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for all input and consideration!

To answer the **original question**:

I have found a very close question on one [German tooling forum](http://werkzeug-news.de/forum/viewtopic.php?t=28230). It contains some additional information. Apparently, there used to be stands able to accept large collar diameter drills, including Metabo's Typ 793. However nobody is aware of anything like that existing today.

My assumption: the problem lies in that the large diameter collar is used in hammers rather than drills. They are not designed to be fixed, since they are not designed to be used as drills in the first place. They are also heavy, so the stand should be *very* heavy.

So the answer to the original question is probably: **it does not exist**.
If someone finds it let them add another answer here.

---

From the useful accessories for 50 mm collar, Metabo offers a dust extraction set [630828000](https://www.metabo.com/com/en/accessories/drills-and-impact-drills/accessories-for-dust-extraction/dust-extraction-set/dust-extraction-set-43-50-mm-630828000.html).

---

What I wanted to have can be done using e.g. [this Wolfcraft](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000JCIMEA) or [this General's](http://www.generaltools.com/precision-drill-guide-with-3-8-in-chuck.html) accessory.

Alternatively, there are accessories that hold the bit itself, something like this: [Wolfcraft 4640000](http://www.wolfcraft.de/de/produkte/p/duebelgeraete/1_meisterduebler/s/p/).

---

I have also found a very similar tool to the above mentioned Metabo UHE 2450, but with a 43 mm collar: Bosch PBH 3000-2 FRE. However, even from the look, it's clear inferior to Metabo. To my astonishment, it has a plastic collar!

I am afraid, you can't have a cake and eat it, so I'll need to choose if I want a universal drill/hammer or something for a stand. And though the drill found by @batsplatsterson is really nice, I start leaning towards giving up the stand/accessory idea: for orthogonal drilling, there is something like this:

Answer (score 5):

You don't want an SDS plus chuck, that drill is going to be mostly for drilling masonry.  You could get an adapter to use regular bits with the SDS chuck but it's not what you really want.

There are drills with a regular three-jaw chuck that have a hammer setting for masonry, they aren't as good as the SDS chuck drills in masonry but more than adequate for general DIY use.

I have a Bosch that's been great, but if you like Metabo, I think these are under Impact Drills on the Metabo site:

https://www.metabo.com/com/en/machines/drilling-screwing-chiselling-stirring/impact-drills/

edit:  the [SBE 900 IMPULS (600865590) IMPACT DRILL](https://www.metabo.com/com/en/machines/drilling-screwing-chiselling-stirring/impact-drills/sbe-900-impuls-600865590-impact-drill.html#description) actually looks super nice, it has the 43mm chuck you want, apparently its set up to be a good driver as well as drill / hammer drill - that looks pretty versatile, I wonder if there's a US version...

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I have seriously considered this option. Eventually I decided to go for the multihammer, since already for hanging a TV people over here suggest getting a proper hammer tool. Also I'll need to hang a lot of things in the utility room, and its all brick.

Comment: BTW, the US version of SBE 900 is [Metabo SBE 900 IMPULS (600865610) IMPACT DRILL](https://www.metabo.com/com/en/machines/drilling-screwing-chiselling-stirring/impact-drills/sbe-900-impuls-600865610-impact-drill.html#description).

Answer (score 1):

50 mm collar drills where very popular in Europe a few years ago, specially for powerful drills - to drill bricks, concrete, steel... - but, now there are drills with similar power with 43 mm collars...

Drilling concrete or stone with those drills is quite simple (they must have the "hammer symbol" and lets put it on, hold the drill and let it do the job - a good drill will work quite fast with "no pain" for the user, BUT, be aware, those have much more torque then you are used to or you can hold - so, don't push it hard, this way avoids de bit get stuck in the hole (DANGER!!!) - remember, concrete have steel rods in it...

Those drills with the "hammer symbol" (from 1800 to 3000 rpm of velocity), they were not made for stands - they are heavy duty tolls - so grab it, drill it, and it's all.

The ones with no such symbol have (normally) 2 gears and speeds from 150 to 2000 rpm and are specially for Steel (never try it in concrete); those were made for hand hold and stands...

I, my self, have 2 drills with 50mm collar (recent acquisitions)- one for concrete/stone; the other is specially for steel and have the same problem has you, stands for 50mm colars are very hard to find (since the 90s they just vanish - but they were quite popular, has the drills were), even in 2nd hand are hard...

There is a point here that is important to mention - stands with 43mm collars are not made for the torque of 50mm drills!!!
And yes! No possible turn a 43 collar in a 50mm... If so, not quite secure...

I'll made one stand for mine   ;)

Hoping reaching you in time...

HFeio